# NSTimeZone localTimeZone vs systemTimeZone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

What is the difference between `[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]` and `[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone - Differences among time zone convenience methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985468/iphone-differences-among-time-zone-convenience-methods)

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSTimeZone: what is the difference between localTimeZone and systemTimeZone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526990/nstimezone-what-is-the-difference-between-localtimezone-and-systemtimezone)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to the [NSTimeZone](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html) reference of iOS, the `systemTimeZone` represents the timezone used by the system (device) itself.

The `localTimeZone` returns an object that represents the current default time zone for the application. The application can change its default timezone via the `setDefaultTimeZone` call.

There are no exposed Cocoa APIs to change the system time zone, or to change another application's time zone.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a object instantiated from the `[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]`, it will be cached by the application and will not reflect the current device's zone until you clear it using `[NSTimeZone resetSystemTimeZone]`.

Use `[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]` instead of `[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]` if you want your timezone variable to reflect any updates to the application's timezone.