# Change current time to Indian standard time

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I am getting current date by using this

```
 NSDate *currDate;
currDate = [NSDate date];
```

But If user opens my app from other country also the currDate should be Indian time only.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this helps, there could be multiple ways of approaching this - but this is readable -

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Asia/Kolkata"]];
NSString *indianTimeZone = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];
NSLog(@"%@", indianTimeZone);
```

I learned about "Asia/Kolkata" by logging -

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames]);
```

Also, checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24930453/3527656), I like this approach.

Comment: Thanks @raurora
+1 for showing all timezones in log

Comment: how to know user timezone?

Comment: You can Google it also. Checkout this answer. Understand `[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]` and `[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477828/nstimezone-localtimezone-vs-systemtimezone