# NSSystemClockDidChangeNotification acts weird when app wakes up

Tags: ios, iphone, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

In my app I'm registering a `NSSystemClockDidChangeNotification` notification in `AppDelegate` method `application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:options`.

> Posted whenever the system clock is changed. This can be initiated by
>   a call to settimeofday() or the user changing values in the Date and
>   Time Preference panel. The notification object is null. This
>   notification does not contain a userInfo dictionary.

Month ago it was working fine, but these days every time I suspend my app, lock my iPhone and leave it 2 minutes to pass, when opening the app, the selector method is called, which is weird to me. I didn't change the system or time, I just let the device idle.

Can anyone help me understand this? I just want to execute some code when the user manually change the system time, just in that case (tried with `UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification` but that doesn't help).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like that: [Getting iOS system uptime, that doesn't pause when asleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488481/getting-ios-system-uptime-that-doesnt-pause-when-asleep/12490414#12490414)

But remember, this solution will fail sometimes because of out-of-sync when system tries to update time from NTP server when the Internet connection is not reachable.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a bit late but this is what the apple support team replied when I ask a similar question:

**Part of the question I asked:**

> Could it be possible for the OS posted [this notification] if the
> time/timezone has not changed in the device?

**The answer I got from them:**

> Absolutely [1].  It's common for a notification like this to be posted
> redundantly.  In some cases it's triggered by a state change you can't
> see.  For example — and I haven't tested this theory, so it's just an
> example of how this sort of thing can come about — this notification
> might be posted if the system's giant list of time zone info has
> changed.  So, the time zone state has changed, but it's not something
> that affects your app.
>
> But in other cases, a notification might be truly redundant (-:  iOS
> is a complex system and in some cases this complex machinery generates
> redundant notifications, and there's no need to filter them out
> because…
>
> Your app should respond to such notifications be refetching the info
> it cares about and updating its state based on that.  If this update
> is expensive, keep your own copy of the previous state, compare the
> current system state to that, and only do the update if the stuff you
> care about has actually changed.