# iOS Device Uptime using Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin

I used to use this code to retrieve the iOS uptime using Xamarin's classic API:

```
var uptime = ObjCRuntime.Messaging.Double_objc_msgSend(NSProcessInfo.ProcessInfo.Handle, 
                                                                  new ObjCRuntime.Selector ("systemUptime").Handle);
var ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(uptime);
return ts;
```

I am trying to convert to the Unified API and now I am getting this build error for the above:-

```
Error CS0122: `ObjCRuntime.Messaging' is inaccessible due to its protection level (CS0122)
```

I am not sure how to convert this.  Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unified api has a ProcessInfo that is shared between iOS and OS-X

So using that with your code/variable names:

```
var uptime = Foundation.NSProcessInfo.ProcessInfo.SystemUptime;
var ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(uptime);
return ts;
```

Comment: Is this the same behavior as this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12490414/2304737?

Comment: @mr5 Per the Apple docs: `The amount of time the system has been awake since the last time it was restarted.`