# Getting system uptime in iOS/Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to get system uptime in iOS (using Swift)? What I need is to measure time without having to worry about the user changing the time. In Android there's a `elapsedCurrentTimeMillis()` that returns the number of milliseconds since boot, but now I need something like that for iOS. There's an accepted answer here [Getting iOS system uptime, that doesn't pause when asleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488481/getting-ios-system-uptime-that-doesnt-pause-when-asleep) but that's for Objective C and I need it for Swift and I don't know how to convert it.

Comment: What about just `NSProcessInfo.processInfo().systemUptime`?

Comment: That doesn't take into account sleep time. I need a way to reliably measure how much time has passed, even if the app is shut down in the meantime and even if the user changes the time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you ask for a pure-Swift solution, I converted the ObjC code from the answer you mentioned [Getting iOS system uptime, that doesn't pause when asleep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12490414/4912403).

```
func uptime() -> time_t {
    var boottime = timeval()
    var mib: [Int32] = [CTL_KERN, KERN_BOOTTIME]
    var size = strideof(timeval)

    var now = time_t()
    var uptime: time_t = -1

    time(&now)
    if (sysctl(&mib, 2, &boottime, &size, nil, 0) != -1 && boottime.tv_sec != 0) {
        uptime = now - boottime.tv_sec
    }
    return uptime
}

// print(uptime())
```

---

To make it a bit prettier, we can use `sysctlbyname` instead of `sysctl`:

```
// var mib: [Int32] = [CTL_KERN, KERN_BOOTTIME]
sysctlbyname("kern.boottime", &boottime, &size, nil, 0)
```

Comment: @JAL I debugged and figured out the different behaviour of sizeof between ObjC and Swift. It works now!

Comment: Yup, this works, shows the same value as Objective-C code version! And I can see I'm going to have a hard time programming...

Comment: i get a `Use of unresolved identifier 'strideof'` error in swift 5. looks like the syntax changed but i am not sure what to

Comment: @Anushk replace `strideof(timeval)` with `MemoryLayout<timeval>.stride`

Answer (score 6):

This is a solution in Swift 4.

```
 var boottime = timeval()
 var size = MemoryLayout<timeval>.stride
 sysctlbyname("kern.boottime", &boottime, &size, nil, 0)
```

Answer (score 6):

Updated for Swift 5 and straight from ADF post [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/101874):

```
func bootTime() -> Date? {  
    var tv = timeval()  
    var tvSize = MemoryLayout<timeval>.size  
    let err = sysctlbyname("kern.boottime", &tv, &tvSize, nil, 0);  
    guard err == 0, tvSize == MemoryLayout<timeval>.size else {  
        return nil  
    }  
    return Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(tv.tv_sec) + Double(tv.tv_usec) / 1_000_000.0)  
}
```

"Be aware that this time will change if the system clock changes, that is, the value is the boot time relative to the current system clock."

Comment: What's the point of boot time that depends on the system clock changes? Did they change this behavior or what?

Answer (score 2):

You can call ObjC code from Swift:

```
print(SystemUtil().uptime());
```

Write a ObjC class like the accepted answer you mentioned: [Getting iOS system uptime, that doesn't pause when asleep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12490414/4912403).

`SystemUtil.h` for interface:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SystemUtil : NSObject

- (time_t)uptime;

@end
```

`SystemUtil.m` for implementation:

```
#import "SystemUtil.h"
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

@implementation SystemUtil

- (time_t)uptime
{
    struct timeval boottime;
    int mib[2] = {CTL_KERN, KERN_BOOTTIME};
    size_t size = sizeof(boottime);
    time_t now;
    time_t uptime = -1;

    (void)time(&now);

    if (sysctl(mib, 2, &boottime, &size, NULL, 0) != -1 && boottime.tv_sec != 0) {
        uptime = now - boottime.tv_sec;
    }
    return uptime;
}

@end
```

And don't forget to include a `<Project>-Bridge-Header.h` with the following content so that you can use the ObjC class from Swift (`<Project>` is your project name):

```
#import "SystemUtil.h"
```

Comment: The OP is asking for a native Swift solution.

Comment: This works. I think. It's showing plausible non-zero uptime. For anyone as dumb as me, all you need to do is create the .h and .m files in Xcode (File->New->File...->iOS->Source) and put in them what @donghua-li wrote, and Bridge-Header.h will be automatically created (so just add the #import)

Comment: @TimSim I've worked out a [pure-Swift solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36204651/4912403).