# Possible with ios 13.6 or ipadios automatically starting an application executing specific actions on ipad startup?

Tags: ios

On iPhone x I am using ios 13.6
on ipad pro 2018 I am using ipadios ( latest version in 10.08.2020)

I want automatically to start an application with defined actions when the device (ipad pro 2018 or iPhone-x-2016) is switched off and than restarts.
remark: battery live doesn't matter

On the former versions I had to use the "kiosk.app"

Now on the latest versions of ios and ipadios will this be the same?
Thank you very much in advance for your help.
remark: I am unable in programming

Thank you very much in advance for your support.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You may need to clarify your question in order to get the best answer.

Comment: You can't force your app to be automatically launched after the device reboots. It is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to run an action in your app after a user restarts their device, you could check the time since the device booted, as explained in [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36203662/getting-system-uptime-in-ios-swift).  You can save the time since the device booted every time the user starts your app.  Before you save the time since device boot, you can check if the previously saved time since boot is greater than the current time since boot.  If it is, then the device has been restarted recently.  This wouldn't work the very first time your app is launched after it is installed, and it wouldn't work if a user didn't open your app for a long time after their device was restarted, since the time since the device booted might be greater than the previously saved time.