# iOS get Last mobile shutdown time

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Is this possible to get Last shutdown or reboot time using objective c or Swift.

I tried many websites and forums. i can't find solution for this problem.

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488481/getting-ios-system-uptime-that-doesnt-pause-when-asleep ?

Answer (score 3):

Check out [NSProcessInfo](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSProcessInfo_Class/index.html) there is a property called systemUptime of type NSTimeInterval

```
NSProcessInfo.processInfo().systemUptime
[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] systemUptime]
```

I gave you your answer in both objective-c and swift since you tagged them both.

Comment: is this to get last shutdown time?

Comment: Please check the documentation, especially I linked for you. This returns The amount of time the system has been awake since the last time it was restarted.

Comment: @PREMKUMAR This will give you the time interval the Mobile has been switched on since the last restart

Answer (score 2):

You cannot detect the last shutdown time. But you can detect the last reboot time as:
`let systemUptime = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().systemUptime;`

And to detect the time, since last reboot is:

```
    let systemUptime = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().systemUptime;
    let timeNow = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
    let dateOfLastReboot = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: timeNow-systemUptime)
```