# Handle app while the device getting switched off

Tags: ios, swift

Can I handle/update app while the device getting switched off in iOS? At least can I get the time when the device got switched off?
Is it possible? If yes, please suggest me the answer. If no, tell me reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was also in the same trouble. see: Getting current time when device was shutting down

I’ve tried out some ways as follows.

1. Getting current time in the applicationWillTerminate: app delegate method It gives the time when the app get terminated by the user. An app get terminated automatically when a device is getting switched off. so here we can get the time when the device is getting switched off. but it works only if the device getting switched when the app is in foreground state. But it wont’s work in back ground. in background mode it gives the last terminated time.
2. If we run the timer every minute/(few seconds) once on background mode and saving (replacing) values in NSUserDefaluts, and if the device is getting switched off the timer will get stopped and we can get the last value saved in the user defaults once after the mobile switched on. It also not consuming more storage.

And now I am Using the above second point. May be its crazy but it works for me.

Comment: Yes, I will try both.

Comment: yes, Got it using the timer running on background for 30 seconds. it works for me.. Thanks a lot...!

Comment: Have you tried it when your app isn't running under Xcode?  The timer won't work in the background if you aren't debugging

Comment: Yes I've tried it and using in one of my working app. And checked out in background mode with the xcode -->window -->devices (log)

Answer (score 0):

You can react depending on the states of your app, from your AppDelegate.

Review **Execution States for Apps** from Apple Documentation, it's well documented

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW3

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there are only few notifications allowed from the UIDevice, you can find them [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/index.html).

There are some undocumented private frameworks, which could provide you such information, but if you use them, your app will be rejected.

But you can use Enterprise Edition to deploy your application.