# What NSTimeZone value does an NSDateFormatter use if you don't pass it in?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdateformatter, nstimezone

What NSTimeZone value does an NSDateFormatter use if you don't pass it in? I'd like to either use the default `timeZone` value, or pass in a given one. I'd like to do something like this:

```
- (NSString *) announcementTime{
    NSTimeZone *defaultTimeZone;  // What does this become?
    [self announcementTimeInTimeZone:defaultTimeZone];
}

- (NSString *) announcementTimeInTimeZone:(NSTimeZone *)timeZone{

  NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

  [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
  [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
  [formatter setTimeZone:timeZone];

  return time;
}
```

What time zone do I want to pass in to my `announcementTimeInTimeZone:` method? Perhaps `[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]` or `[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]`. I'm just not sure what the default is and don't see it documented anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find any documentation either but I had a play in the debugger and it looks like NSDateFormatter uses defaultTimeZone.

> (lldb) p (NSTimeZone*)[f timeZone] (NSTimeZone *) $1 = 0x0a926fa0
> @"Australia/Sydney"
>
> (lldb) p (NSTimeZone*)[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]
> (NSTimeZone *) $2 = 0x0a926fa0 @"Australia/Sydney"
>
> (lldb) po [NSTimeZone localTimeZone]
> (id) $2 = 0x0ab3bb10 Local Time Zone (Australia/Sydney (GMT+10:00) offset 36000)

*"f"* is an NSDateFormatter created just with alloc - init.
As you can see the two time zones are exactly the same, stored at the same address.

Comment: Yes, I added it to the answer above. They are different.

Comment: This answer has some pretty good explanation on the timezone types. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526990/nstimezone-what-is-the-difference-between-localtimezone-and-systemtimezone

Comment: It is stated in the [Data Formatting Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1), though not quite explicitly: «In all cases, you should consider that formatters default to using the user’s locale (`currentLocale`) superimposed with the user’s preference settings.» The locale includes a time zone.

Answer (score 0):

It will take a `localTimeZone` by default.