# get timezone from an iOS device requesting a web api in php

Tags: php, ios, api, timezone, nstimezone

i am developing an API for a iOS app. I need to get the timezone of the iphone that is requesting the web api.

the normal way is to get it by fetching the ip when the user loads the page, but how do i get the timezone for an iOS device connectin my app ?

Comment: Well what have you tried? `[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]` will give you the current devices time zone.

Comment: @rckoenes - i need to do this in php

Comment: If you need to do it in PHP then this is not an iOS or `NSTimeZone` question, because it doesn't matter what OS the client side is running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to first get an [`NSTimeZone`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html) object using the iOS functions - either [`systemTimeZone`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimeZone/systemTimeZone) or [`localTimeZone`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimeZone/localTimeZone) ([see here for differences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1526990/634824)).  The [`name`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimeZone/name) property of the `NSTimeZone` object should give you back a string with a standard [IANA TZ database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) identifier, such as `"America/New_York"`.  That's what you send to your web service.  The fact that your web service is written in PHP does not matter from the iOS environment.

However, these time zone identifiers are indeed the same ones used by PHP, as seen in the [list of support time zones](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).  You can use the with functions like [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php), or with a [`DateTimeZone`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) object that you can pass when working with a [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).