# Is there any way to find difference between Current time zone date or time and system time in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, cllocationmanager

I need to calculate time difference between current device located time zone time and system time(iphone and ipad)if the user time changes manually current device date or time. If it set automatic i am able to get but if user changes manually date or time i facing problem.

Comment: Current device located time & System time (iPhone and iPad). Don't you think these are both same?

Comment: Ya its same.. there only my problem came, Actually i am calculating time difference for delta value to reach server. If its automatic i am getting exact time zone. but after changing the timezone user changes time his manually some hours before or after.. then on that time i need to find timezone to time how many hours difference

Answer (score 1):

The app or user may change either the default time zone for an application (using +[NSTimeZone setDefaultTimeZone]) or the system time zone (using System Preferences) at any time. +[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] returns a proxy that will always act as if it is the current default time zone for the application, even if that default changes. You could change the default time zone for an application to make it behave as if it were in a different time zone.

+[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] returns the current system time zone (as set using System Preferences). In most cases, these will be the same (the app's default time zone is set to the system time zone at app startup, I believe).

If you want to know the system's time zone setting, you probably want to use +[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]. If you just want the correct time zone for your app to work in, you probably want +[NSTimeZone localTimeZone].

refere to the link:
[NSTimeZone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526990/nstimezone-what-is-the-difference-between-localtimezone-and-systemtimezone)

Answer (score 0):

You have to take care when user change time zone or time.

There is one delegate method in `UIApplication.h` class.

```
- (void)applicationSignificantTimeChange:(UIApplication *)application;        // midnight, carrier time update, daylight savings time change
```

Override this method in `AppDelegate.m`. It will call whenever use change device time zone.

So you can store previous time in `NSUserDefaults` and then in this method measure time difference with new time.

Also there is one notification observer `UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification`. Add this observer to your view controller.

For Example:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(timeChanged:) name:UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification object:nil];

- (void)timeChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
}
```