# Local notification set default time 9:00 am for user timezone in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, timezone

I want set notification **default 9:00** am for every user timezone time.

How to create **fire date** for default time **9:00 am**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I got it this Ans:-

```
NSDate *pickerDate = [NSDate date]; 
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:DT_FORMATE_BIRTHDATE];
    NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:DT_TIME_ZONE_GMT];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit )
                                                   fromDate:pickerDate];
    [timeComponents setHour:9];
    [timeComponents setMinute:00];
    [timeComponents setSecond:0];

    NSDate *dtFinal = [calendar dateFromComponents:timeComponents];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];

    NSString *fierDate = [formatter stringFromDate:dtFinal];
```

Comment: What is `DT_TIME_ZONE_GMT` here?

Comment: DT_TIME_ZONE_GMT      = @"GMT"

Answer (score 0):

1. [This](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/) is a full tutorial regarding Local Notification
2. Below is Solve issue of timezone which mention above. Please review these timezone function in details and set appropriate timezone in your function.

---

```
[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]

[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]

[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]
```

[NSTimeZone: what is the difference between localTimeZone and systemTimeZone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526990/nstimezone-what-is-the-difference-between-localtimezone-and-systemtimezone)

Comment: #Renish  You are right but i need set default time for every timezone so i got Ans form above. Thank you for Ans.

Comment: @mitulmarsonia, if you get user device timezone(Get User Device time!) then no need more work. What should you think?

Comment: device timezone get easy but i dont know how to set our time in this so i have this kind of question. Now i got it how to set our default time in any time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
 NSDate *pickerDate = [date_picker date];
// Schedule the notification
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = pickerDate;
localNotification.alertBody = @"Alert Body Message";
localNotification.alertAction = @"Alert Action Message";
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```